# CS cart shipping condition

Tags: cs-cart

I am using CS cart and I have problem with my shipping method. Basically I provide free shipping on specific products when their total exceeds 500 and other products have shipping even those that exceed 500 or not.

The problem is that when our free shipping products exceed $500 and if we choose some other products so it calculates as a free shipping. How can I modify its calculation?

Comment: you can't do this yet in cs-cart's promotion system, your problem will be solved only if you use a 3d party add-on

Answer (score 0):

to use different shipping charges for products within one order, you can set different suppliers for different products: the products from the “free shipping for products over $500” category will be assigned to one supplier with the free shipping method, while the rest of your products will be assigned to the other supplier with another shipping method. As a result, shipping cost will be calculated separately for several products in one order.

Here is the instruction on how to set up the suppliers’ functionality:

http://kb.cs-cart.com/suppliers-functionality

CS-Cart Team

http://www.cs-cart.com